# Retina 3.5 has wrong origin after rotation in modal view to UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, modalviewcontroller, retina-display

I have a weird behaviour with my view representation.

my structure:

```
Window -> MyTabbarController -> GraphViewController -> (modal) SelectItemViewController;
```

settings of Window:

[image]

After I updated my app to the **retina 4 resolution** (and set the `UIWindow` size in the Window.xib to **Retina 4 fullscreen**), the `origin` of `myTabbarController` was set to 0,88 in the **Retina 3.5 devices** (in retina 4 there are no problems).

[image]

If I use `non-modal` controllers, I can rotate till end of days, everything works fine.

But if I call the `modal view` in `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` (for `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight` works everything fine) or `dismiss` the `modalView` in same state, the `parentView` of `GraphViewController` (`MyTabbarController`) gets a wrong frame...

**CALL** the modal view:
[image]

**DISMISS** the modal view
[image]

I am thankfull for every help.

ps: setting the `UIWindow` size to **Retina 3.5 fullscreen** or **freeform** makes it looking wrong in **iPhone 5**. Also setting the `modalPresentationStyle` doesn't do anything :/

Comment: did you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, there were 2 things I had to do. the one was setting the size of the Applicationwindow and for the other I need to search tomorrow, don't have my code here

Comment: If you can - put the full answer on this issue and accept it - I follow this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by setting the window size in code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    window.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
    ...
```

after setting this, the frame was always set on the correct position.

I think it was just a problem of the binding of the view to the window and it's orientation in this "container" (screen has a 'width' of **480** but frame **568** pixel in landscape mode. And the gray part was just this difference (88 pixel) to the right (non-bounded) side of the modal view)